# Syntax Errors Compiling HLSDK for Windows CE on SH-4

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, windows-ce, visual-c++-6

first question here. This may sound silly to many here, but this is my first dabble in coding. Hopefully I do not get too much flame

I'm compiling HLSDK source code using Visual C++ 6.0, with the Sega Dreamcast (Official) toolkit. The sources I have were already ported for the platform I'm compiling for, I got about 50 errors down to the final 3. They are syntax errors on [pm_math.c](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/halflife/blob/master/pm_shared/pm_math.c)

The line at fault according to compiler is

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
printf("test\n");
return 0;
}
```

Advice I've gotten from others say that looks fine, but it may be a string above that breaks that one below

[Errors from compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyIa3.jpg)

Is there any VC++6.0 expert advice someone can give me to get this to compile? As I've said these are the final 3 errors, everything else builds

---

Apologies for the long post, and lack of compiler information. If someone could tell me how to find that out. I'll gladly provide the info

I'm not sure where else to turn on the internet for assistance with this. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I believe, you indent your code properly and you'll get to see the error. :)

Comment: The code is actually indented in VS, I typed that by hand and forgot to indent. If I can fix that one string this will compile